# get directory from fullname, rename directory

Tags: powershell

i want to find all files with more than 256 characters in fullname.

From these files i want to rename the folder.

At the morment i'm at this point

```
    $maxLength = 260
    $newPath = "a_path"

$paths = Get-ChildItem $newPath -force -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) } |
    % {
     Write-Host $_.FullName
}
```

But now I'm lost.

1. I can't understand why the command write-host $paths doesn't work anymore.
2. From the fullname I only need the directory, i tried to get it with

   select Directory
   or
   Splith-Path

But this also doesn't work.

3. How can I say to "trim" the directory name to $maxLength = 260

Thank's for a few hints!

CYA_D0c

Comment: `$paths` is empty because the only "output" is from `write-host` and that command doesn't write to the success stream. Use `write-output` instead or output `$_.FullName` without a command for it to be stored in the variable. For `split-path`, you will need to provide the `FullName` property value of your object. For `.Directory`, it produces a directory object so you also need an additional property like `.Directory.FullName`. For max length, you can use `-replace` --> `$_.Directory.FullName -replace '(?<=.{260}).*'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. I can't understand why the command `write-host $paths` doesn't work
>      anymore.

Replace the `Write-Host` cmdlet by `Select-Object`:

```
$maxLength = 260
$newPath = "a_path"
$paths = Get-ChildItem $newPath -Force -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

`$paths` will then be a list of your desired full paths.

> 2. From the fullname I only need the directory, i tried to get
>      it with 
>      `select Directory` or `Splith-Path`. 
>      But this also doesn't work.

`Splith-Path` will do it:

```
$paths | Split-Path -Parent
```

> 3. How can I say to "trim" the directory name to $maxLength = 260

That's not that easy as you might think. To what name do you want to trim it? What if the trimmed name of a directory already exists?

Of course you can rename a directory at any time, but you need a certain naming convention if you want to trim directory names to a certain length automatically.

What's your original problem? Are you still using Windows 7 or old MS Office products that are limitted to a maximum path length of 256?

Comment: i'm moving several files from directory to find duplicates and rename them on Windows 10 Client. It works correctly. Now for the first time the were failueres, because of to long path length. Now I want to rename the folder. It's not allowed to rename the files. 1 and 2 work perfect. For 3 yes good hint that the directory could already exist. The Original Folder Name doesn't matter, so i can rename it to any name i want. May for uniqueness i should use date/time(with milliseconds)

Comment: @D0c_cR4Zy Keep in mind that a full path not only contains the name of one folder, but the chain of all parent folders. What folder dou you want to rename? The leaf folder? What if the path with all parent folders already exceeds 256 characters? Then it won't be sufficient to just rename the leaf folder. It will get very complicated I think. It might be a better idea to manually rename some folders. You now get a list aof all paths that you should review.

Comment: The more I think about your answer it will be more safely to do it in another way. How can i count the results, then i will do if count -gt 0 then $paths | Export-Csv C:\PathTo\MyCooL.csv and exit else go on

Comment: @D0c_cR4Zy Just: `if ($paths.Count -gt 0) {$paths | Export-Csv C:\PathTo\MyCooL.csv}`.

Comment: Ah I see... You can use `Out-File` in this scenario, if a text file is enough for you: `if ($paths.Count -gt 0) {$paths | Out-File C:\PathTo\MyCooL.txt}` or don't use `-ExpandProperty` but `-Property` in the `Select-Object` cmdlet (see my answer) and then the `Export-Csv` in my previous comment will work.

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host` is only for sending text characters to your terminal, be it the PowerShell Prompt or something else, and you can't catch it in a variable like you're trying to do.

We can simplify your code to this, to get only those paths longer than 260.

```
$paths = Get-ChildItem $newPath -force -Recurse | 
    Where-Object { ($_.FullName.Length -gt $maxLength) } | Select-Object -Expand Fullname
```

Which should give you just a listing of the directories which are too long, stored inside of `$paths`.  You could export it to a csv file like so:

```
$paths | Export-Csv C:\PathTo\MyCooL.csv
```

#### And it is at this point that you should pause and decide how to proceed.

This sort of process is often attempted and we have, as a hive-mind, determined that it is not an ideal candidate for automation.  Instead, a person should review the list and then intelligently make the right decision to rename the directories.

Why? It would be very easy to break some apps if your renaming script ran amuk in `C:\ProgramData\`, for instance.  On looking at the list, you might find deeply nested installs containing Visual C++ Redistributables, or other important content.  You'll need to make the right call on how to rename it, to do so safely.